# Perl encode_json function is not formatting correctly

Tags: perl

I have a few files full of IP addresses, one address per line. I want to combine them all together into one JSON file in this format:

```
["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"]
```

I then want to write this to a new file. Please see my code and see my outputs at two different stages. I think it is a simple problem to fix but I am not seeing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#install JSON module 'sudo cpanm JSON'
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;

my %data;
my @FILES = glob("/home/jamie/store/inbound/threatfeeds/*_ip");

# 1. Open and load each file    
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    local $/ = undef;
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    $data{$file} = <$fh>;
}

foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    $data{$file} = qx(/bin/cat "$file");
}

use File::Slurp;
foreach my $file (@FILES) {
    $data{$file} = File::Slurp::slurp($file);
}

#convert hash array to JSON
#print %data;
my $json_output = encode_json \%data;
print $json_output;
```

The output as the code stands currently is something similar to this:

```
216.243.31.254\n195.239.244.122\n103.10.133.179\n198.13.96.39\n198.13.96.59\n198.13.96.233\n104.167.119.161\n193.201.227.90\n208.67.1.21\n175.139.186.213
```

If I uncomment `print %data` and comment out `print $json_output`, I get a list of IP addresses similar to this:

```
109.161.206.153
91.205.173.220
66.196.243.4
```

Comment: Please don't give us 'something similar to' - we need a solid example. And an example of input is good too.

Comment: Why are you reading the files **three times** and overwriting the existing data with each subsequent iteration?

Comment: Sobrique - in what way is it not a solid example? It showed enough of each output to symbolize the pattern. If I pasted the whole output there wouldn't be enough character count... these files are massive.

I didn't provide an example of input as I made it clear that the input were files with IP addresses separated by line, which I thought was clear. Sorry if not, am new to this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what you want is `pretty_print`:

```
print to_json ( \%data, { 'pretty_print' => 1 } );
```

But can I also point out - it's thoroughly nasty to `system` `cat`. Perl has perfectly good `open` system calls.

Especially as you basically do it twice and clobber your data in the process.

Why *are* you trying to embed all of a file into a json structure as plain text?

Do you mean that you are *perhaps* trying to make a JSON array with one IP per element? Because what you're doing... isn't going to work.

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#install JSON module 'sudo cpanm JSON'
use warnings;
use strict;
use JSON;
use autodie;

my @data;

foreach my $file ( glob("/home/jamie/store/inbound/threatfeeds/*_ip") ) {
    open( my $input, "<", $file );
    while (<$input>) {
        chomp;
        my ($ip_addr) = m/([\d\.]+)/;
        push( @data, $ip_addr );
    }
    close($input);
}

my $json_output = to_json( \@data, { pretty => 1 } );
print $json_output;
```

Assuming your files are just a list of IP addresses, this will give you an 'ip' json array 'looking like':

```
[
    "10.1.2.3",
    "192.168.0.22",
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got the system cat code from online and it seemed to do (nearly) what I wanted to I stuck with it. I will do some research into Perl open calls and try to use these instead.

I basically have multiple files of IP addresses that I need into a JSON file so that this can be read into an API that accepts bulk IP addresses in JSON format.

Comment: If you can give examples of input/output I can improve my answer.

Comment: this does not work, output is just loads of "[1]". It is not necessary for a regex because all the input files already have correct ip addresses formatted on each line.

Comment: Sorry, minor typo there - try again and it'll work. Doesn't need a regex, but I wasn't entirely sure what your input format was because you didn't post it. Bear in mind though - you do have to do some transformation (e.g. `chomp`) as your input will include linefeeds.

Comment: Great, thanks! I cleaned it up a bit myself and removed the regex.

Comment: any chance you know why when I apply this same logic to my domain list (I took out the regex) that my formatting is messing up by it adding random "\t" ?: ["000cc.com\t","1-verygoods.ru\t","114bds.com\t","120a.com\t","123mdw.com\t","1492tapasbar.com\t","18dd.net\t","19tenco.com\t","1aurlaub-machen.de\t","1sense.info\t","1trillionemails.com\t","1verygoods.ru\t","2009dddd.cn\t","2009mmmm.cn\t","2013-verygoods.ru\t","2112111.com\t","230x.net\t","24-procent.ru\t","249

Should I ask a new question with my new code? I am new to Stackoverflow

Comment: Well, put the regex back in and it won't!. But I'd guess you have a trailing tab in your file.

Comment: The regex is fine for my IP addresses, but I am wanting to do the exact same procedure but for a list of domain's as well. e.g. www.domain.com or domain2.biz etc into JSON

Comment: `[\w\.]+` is a quick sanitisation for that :).

Answer (score 1):

In your attempts to *slurp* the data into a single scalar, you are creating a single string when you want an array of IP addresses

Something like this will work for you

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %data;
my @files = glob '/home/jamie/store/inbound/threatfeeds/*_ip';

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    chomp ( my @lines = <$fh> );
    $data{$file} = \@lines;
}

my $json_output = encode_json \%data;
print $json_output;
```

---

#### Update

Okay, so you want just a list of IP addresses. That's very simple to achieve

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my @files = glob '/home/jamie/store/inbound/threatfeeds/*_ip';

my @data;

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file;
    chomp ( my @lines = <$fh> );
    push @data, @lines;
}

my $json_output = encode_json \@data;
print $json_output;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is the accepted answer. This code will not create output in the format requested by the original poster.

Comment: @MattJacob: I suspect the OP's description is wrong. Their code seemed to be adding a list of IP addresses *per file* to the hash, except that the addresses were in one long string rather than in separate elements of an array. I took a guess that the *"in this format"* is meant to be *per file* and I seem to have guessed right

Comment: @Borodin Actually, this code prints the name of the original ip address file in the JSON output, I don't want this. I simply want an output file of IP addresses only, e.g. ["1.1.1.1","2.2.2.2","3.3.3.3"] and not 

{"/home/jamie/store/inbound/threatfeeds/emergingthreats2_ip":["1.171.135.250","1.172.11.224","1.233.92.197"]

I am new to Perl, I understand all of your code apart from $data{$file} = \@lines; - how can I edit this to get what I want to achieve?

Comment: @Jamie: Ah okay. So Matt Jacob is right! I assumed you wanted the addresses divided by their source file as that's what you wrote in your Perl code. I've added an update to my solution toi show you how to just combine them all into an array

Answer (score 0):

The step you're missing is processing the lines and building the array of IP addresses.

```
use File::Slurp;
use JSON;

my @ips;

for my $file (@FILES) {
    my @lines = read_file($file);

    for my $line (@lines) {
        chomp($line);
        next unless $line =~ /\S/;
        push(@ips, $line);
    }
}

write_file('/path/to/output.json', encode_json(\@ips));
```

Comment: To whomever downvoted this answer: could you explain the reason for the downvote?